# Get element at a specific position in a string with separator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the following user defined function in order to get the element at the position `POSI` (starting at 0) in the string `EXPR`. Each element is separated by a separator (`SEP`).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getStringElement_Expr_Pos_Sep]
( 
  @EXPR nvarchar(MAX),
  @POSI int,
  @SEP nchar
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@POSI < 0)
  BEGIN
    RETURN N'ERROR'
  END

  -- determine the occurrence of SEP in EXPR
  DECLARE @NB_SEP int
  SET @NB_SEP = LEN(@EXPR) - LEN(REPLACE(@EXPR, @SEP, ''))

  -- if there is no SEP -> return original EXPR
  IF (@NB_SEP = 0)
  BEGIN
    RETURN @EXPR
  END

  -- if POSI is higher than number of SEP -> return ERROR
  IF (@POSI > @NB_SEP)
  BEGIN
    RETURN N'ERROR'
  END

  DECLARE @i int = 0

  WHILE (@i < (@POSI))
  BEGIN
    SET @EXPR = SUBSTRING(@EXPR, LEN(LEFT(@EXPR, CHARINDEX(@SEP, @EXPR))) + 1, LEN(@EXPR))
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END

  IF (@POSI = @NB_SEP)
  BEGIN
    RETURN @EXPR
  END

  RETURN LEFT(@EXPR, CHARINDEX(@SEP, @EXPR) - 1)
END
```

For example, if I want to get the 3rd element (`cc`) in the string `aaa|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e`, I will call the UDF as below:

```
SELECT dbo.getStringElement_Expr_Pos_Sep(N'aaa|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e', 2, N'|')
```

Is there a more direct way to achieve the same result ? If not, are there things I could improve in my implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Your function seems fine and is suitable and is likely to perform well unless you pass in large expression pushing the varchar(max) limit. However, I would edit it to check if the first index in the expression is the separator since if it isn't, your function would return undesired results. For example, 
>   `SELECT dbo.getStringElement_Expr_Pos_Sep(N'aaa|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e', 2, N'|')` with your current function returns `cc` not `zzzzz` and calling it with 3 returns `mmmmmm`. So your function is 0 index based (not 1) which you stated, but isn't intuitive for the SQL language as most functions are 1 based. It also doesn't account for the first element being the separator (potentially)

**Long Version**

One alternative option would be to use a string splitter and avoid the while loop in your current function. So, using Jeff Moden's splitter [located here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) where he explains some performance issues with other splitters, you could achieve your results as such:

```
declare @EXPR nvarchar(MAX),
        @POSI int,
        @SEP nchar

set @EXPR = '|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e'
set @POSI = 2
set @SEP = '|'

select * 
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@EXPR,@SEP)
where ItemNumber = @POSI
```

Generally speaking, loops are slow in SQL Server and *most* RDMS. Also, as you can imagine, you can use the string splitter to bring back and entire table of elements which have a greater use case than your current function, reducing code maintenance. **In this case, however, it depends on the length of your expression**

Here is the test I ran:

```
set statistics time on

select * 
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e','|')
where ItemNumber = 66

SELECT dbo.getStringElement_Expr_Pos_Sep('|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e|zzzzz|cc|mmmmm|e', 66, '|')

set statistics time off
```

**Results in Avg**

```
Position 66
Splitter = 3ms 
YourFun  = 6ms

Position 12
Splitter = 2ms 
YourFun  = 4ms

Position 3
AVG
Splitter = 2ms 
YourFun  = 3ms
```

**Bias**

However, if you are reduce the size of the expression to something small like your original use case, your function will run faster by a millisecond, so if you don't expect large expressions, or don't care about milliseconds, your function seems quite suitable.

**Here is the full function**

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]    Script Date: 05/01/2017 9:42:33 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. If the first element is the separator, I don't really know what I expect as result. An empty string as the first element doesn't seem to be a bad solution imo. Your alternative looks good anyway. :)